# mkcert: Your connection is not private

Tags: node.js, operating-system, vite, mkcert

Hello everyone I am use vite with vite-plugin-mkcert, i run this commands:

```
mkcert -install
mkcert localhost 

npm run dev
```

and on site i get this:

[image]
[image]
[image]

my vite config is:

```
import {defineConfig} from'vite'
import mkcert from 'vite-plugin-mkcert'

export default defineConfig({
  server: {
    https: true
  }, // Not needed for Vite 5+ (simply omit this option)
  plugins: [mkcert()]
})
```

**UPDATE**

Without `vite-plugin-mkcert` my proxy server throw `[DEPTH_ZERO_SELF_SIGNED_CERT] (https://nodejs.org/api/errors.html#errors_common_system_errors)`